# python garbage collector doesn't collect?

Tags: python, garbage-collection

trying to figure out when garbage collector collects and what it collects,

```
import gc
a = 1
print(gc.get_count())
a = 2
print(gc.get_count())
a = 3
print(gc.get_count())
gc.collect()
print(gc.get_count())
print(a)
```

output:

```
(101, 5, 3)
(128, 5, 3)
(128, 5, 3)
(0, 0, 0)
3
```

why it prints a after (0, 0, 0)?
from what i understood it cleans reference cycles only, if it is why do i get (0, 0, 0)?
variable a need to promoted to second level?

Comment: if you want to clean the reference `a` you can use `del a`. `collect()` will clean the memory, not references.

Comment: if im cleaning my memory, it should clean my variables too?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1316793/6252134

Comment: can't understand, i can del them without the collector, what the collector does? I've seen it free the reference cycles that stuck, if it is variable a should be promoted to second generation am i wrong?

Comment: if you `del` their reference, you are also telling the collector to collect their real memory as they are unreachable. Then you can do `collect()`.

Comment: then why there is del or why do i get (0, 0, 0)?